# A different way to calculate number of primes less than a particular number x

Tags: prime-numbers, golden-ratio

According to Wikipedia, series representation of logarithmic integral function is as follows:
[image: Logarithmic integral function wikipedia]

Now, as per my findings from [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1428299/is-it-meaningful-in-attempting-to-prove-relation-between-prime-numbers-and-golde?noredirect=1) we can also calculate number of primes less than a particular number x as follows: 
$$f(x) = \sum_{i=2}^{x^{1/\phi}} {i^{1/\phi}\over \ln (i)}$$
Where $\phi$ is the golden ratio.

This formula works at par with the logarithmic integral li(x) and as per my findings it works as prominent as logarithmic integral.

In below graphs, it can be seen that li(x) superimposes the above proposed function. (Both graphs have >1B Prime Numbers)

[image: Graph 1]

[image: Graph 2]

I am trying following things:

1. I am trying an **alternative solution** for estimating number of primes less than a particular number x.
2. I am trying to establish a relationship between **golden ratio** and **prime numbers** as it has always been speculated.
3. I am trying to establish a **finiteness** in estimating the number of primes as the method proposed is a finite series.

Is this work interesting and worth publishing?
Shall I go forward with these findings?

Comment: is your $\phi$ really $\frac{\sqrt 5+1}{2}$?

Comment: @NikolayGromov Yes, it is.

Comment: Look at the upper bound: It must be an integer and therefore your function is a non-continous step function (whatever you do witt the real upper bound: floor, ceil, round...). And as the answer shows, even if it is an integer your function differs from $\mathrm{li}$.

Comment: @gammatester It sums up approximately to li(x) as this can be seen from the graphs. For an instance, if upper bound comes as 18.4, then I go upto 19 and take 40% of what comes between 18 to 19. This much approximation I am doing.

Comment: Could you reformulate your statement in a mathematically sounding way? If that is just about the large $x$ approximation then 
$$ \frac{x \left(\log ^6(x)+\log ^5(x)+2 \log ^4(x)+6 \log ^3(x)+24 \log ^2(x)+120 \log (x)+720\right)}{\log ^7(x)} $$ will give a much better approximation

Comment: You should edit the post and clearly state that this is not an representation but an **approximation** of $\mathrm{li}.$ **And it is a very slow approximation.** If you want to compute $\mathrm{li}(10^{10})$ you have about 1.5 mio terms  and the last term is still $\approx 461$ compared to the result $\approx 455055614$. . I guess nobody needs such a slow process. But if you give a background why this approximation is valid, may be someone is interested.

Comment: @gammatester Sir, I have edited my question. Could you now guide me whether I should go ahead with these findings?

Comment: Your approximation of $\pi(x)$ does **not** have a finite number of terms, they increase as $\approx x^{0.618}$. I am no expert but if you look at the table
http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PrimeCountingFunction.html
I guess your method would be interesting if it would give the exact value $\pi(x)$. But it does not, and there are more efficient approximations.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is `No' just because the statement is wrong. Take $x=2^\phi$. The rhs of your relation gives
$$\frac{2^{1/\phi}}{\ln(2)}\simeq 2.21422$$ whereas
$$li(2^\phi)\simeq 2.22625$$

Comment: I have edited my question to provide some more insights. I understand that there is a small difference in decimals. But, as we go up the number line, we get more and more promising results.

Comment: You should correct the relation. How the plots can change the fact that the rhs and the lhs are not the same?

Comment: What I am trying to say is that as $\pi (x)$ ~ li(x), the above function f(x) ~ li(x) ~ $\pi (x)$. Is this not an interesting finding?

Comment: It is not a finding at all until you specify what '$\sim$' means